# How to write data into a xml file inside the folder in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using the opencv to write / read some data from the file. Here is the structure of my code and the config file.

```
/src/test.cpp
/src/config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml
```

The code is

```
CvFileStorage * fs = cvOpenFileStorage(".config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml",0,CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
cvWriteInt(fs,"enableThreshold",21);
cvReleaseFileStorage(&fs);
```

This doesn't work. I was given the same error for

' OpenCV Error: Null pointer (Invalid pointer to file storage) in cvWriteInt, file    /home/winawer/Downloads/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 2964
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

However, if I change to file to the same level with the source code,

```
/src/test.cpp
/src/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml
```

and
`CvFileStorage * fs = cvOpenFileStorage("FrameDifferenceBGS.xml",0,CV_STORAGE_WRITE);`

This works.

so my question is how to write the data into a file which is on a different level with the source code ?

Solution:
 Now I figure out the solution, which I should put the config folder in the project debug folder rather than the project source folder

Comment: maybe because `config` != `.config`?

Comment: './config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml' or '/config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml' or 'config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml'  don't work as well

Comment: You should be using the C++ API, as in `cv::FileStorage` , rather than the deprecated C API. See http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `/`:

```
CvFileStorage * fs = cvOpenFileStorage(".config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml",0,CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
```

should be

```
CvFileStorage * fs = cvOpenFileStorage("./config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml",0,CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
```

You get the null pointer error because `cvOpenFileStorage()` fails as there is no directory called `.config`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the relative path, the correct format is:

```
"./config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml"
```

or

```
/config/FrameDifferenceBGS.xml
```

Now, you should know the base (root) path for this relative path. As I know relative paths are relative to the *Output Directory*.
If you work in debug mode, your project output directory is *Debug* folder, otherwise it is Release folder.